# How many buttons can a UINavigationController have

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

How many buttons can go on the buttonbar at the top of a NavigationController for the iPad?

I would like to put 3-4 buttons at the top. Do I need to create my own toolbar and not use the one that comes with the UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar doesn't have an explicit limit, but I would be reasonable when it came to the number of buttons I add to it.

Comment: How do you had 3 buttons to the leftButtonBar?